# Is there a better solution to this loop?

Tags: php

I'm making a website which basically displays a random image but I need a better bit of code of what I have at the moment. I'm hoping someone could come up with a better solution.

```
$p = $_GET["p"];
$qrynumrows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($qrynumrows);

if (!isset($p)) {
    $randid = rand(1, $numrows);
    $qryrecord = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE id='$randid'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qryrecord)) {
        $rowp = $row["p"];
        $rowremove = $row["remove"];
    }

    if ($rowremove == 1) {
        header("Location: http://www.lulzorg.com/");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        header("Location: http://www.lulzorg.com/?p=$rowp");
        exit();
    }       
}
```

So what it's doing is picking a random record from the database but it needs to check whether the record is allowed. The bit of code works fine but I'm sure there's a better/faster way to do it.

If $rowremove is equal to 0 then the image is allowed to display. If $rowremove is equal to 1 then the image is NOT allowed to display.

Thanks.

Comment: why is $rowp and $rowremovep being overwritten every time the loop is running? surely thats not what u want?

Comment: Then a while loop is not necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating a random ID, just select the first row after ordering the results by `RAND()`. In addition, check for `NOT remove` (equivalent to `remove = 0`) in the rows to remove the need to check the rows individually.

```
$p = $_GET["p"];

if (is_int($p))
{
    $qryrecord = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT p FROM pictures WHERE NOT remove ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"));
    $rowp = $qryrecord[0];
    header("Location: http://www.lulzorg.com/?p=$rowp");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to get rid of the `$randid` thing - you just replaced it with a better solution and besides that it's most likely broken (see the comment in my answer)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Thanks, just noticed that. I copied his original query and forgot to remove the first condition.

Comment: You might also want to fix the `isset` check to avoid a notice.

Answer (score 1):

IDs are not necessarily consecutive so your way to get a random row is most likely broken.

The easiest way to get a single random row is this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE remove = 0 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Since you only get one row, there's no need for a loop:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryrecord);
```

And then simply use `$row['p']` if `$row != false`:

```
header("Location: http://www.lulzorg.com/?p='.$row['p']);
exit;
```

Here's the whole code you need:

```
$p = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 0;
if (!$p) {
    $qryrecord = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE remove = 0 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryrecord);
    if(!$row) {
        // No valid row. Do something.
        exit;
    }
    header('Location: http://www.lulzorg.com/?p=' . $row['p']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Even though you could have done it, too - you seem to have way enough rep to edit other people's answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE id='$randid' AND rowremove == 0
```

With that, your whole thing can easily be rewritten as:

```
$p = $_GET["p"];

if (!isset($p)) 
{
    $randid = rand(1, $numrows);
    $qryrecord = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE id='$randid' AND rowremove == 0");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($qryrecord);

    if($row)
    {
        $rowp = $row["p"];
        header("Location: http://www.lulzorg.com/?p=$rowp");
        exit();
    }
    header("Location: http://www.lulzorg.com/");
}
```